# Failed to configure a DataSource: 'url' attribute is not specified and no embedded datasource could be configured

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, kotlin, gradle

Ola, estou com problemas em iniciar o springboot com kotlinWeb usando banco mysql

> Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report
> re-run your application with 'debug' enabled. 2022-09-22 21:00:48.034
> ERROR 7166 --- [           main]
> o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   :
>
> *************************** APPLICATION FAILED TO START
>
> ---
>
> Description:
>
> Failed to configure a DataSource: 'url' attribute is not specified and
> no embedded datasource could be configured.
>
> Reason: Failed to determine a suitable driver class
>
> Action:
>
> Consider the following:   If you want an embedded database (H2, HSQL or
> Derby), please put it on the classpath.   If you have database settings
> to be loaded from a particular profile you may need to activate it (no
> profiles are currently active).

**Configurações do gradle**

```
import org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile

plugins {
    id("org.springframework.boot") version "2.7.3"
    id("io.spring.dependency-management") version "1.0.13.RELEASE"
    kotlin("jvm") version "1.6.21"
    kotlin("plugin.spring") version "1.6.21"
    //kotlin("plugin.jpa") version "1.4.30"
}


group = "com.mercadolivro"
version = "0.0.1-SNAPSHOT"
java.sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_11

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")
    implementation("com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-kotlin")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8")
    runtimeOnly("mysql:mysql-connector")
    //runtimeOnly("com.h2database:h2")
    implementation("org.flywaydb:flyway-core:7.7.0")



    testImplementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test")
}

tasks.withType<KotlinCompile> {
    kotlinOptions {
        freeCompilerArgs = listOf("-Xjsr305=strict")
        jvmTarget = "11"
    }
}

tasks.withType<Test> {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

**1. configurações o yml**

```
spring:
jpa:
  hibernate:
    ddl-auto: update
datasource:
  url: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mercadolivro?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true
  username: root
  password: P@ssWord1234
```

Comment: olá Rafael, evite usar imagens, coloque o código na pergunta é melhor para visualizar

Comment: @RicardoPontual feito,  vc consegue ajudar?Meu banco esta ativo

Answer (score 0):

Ola , consegui resolver o problema utilizando o aplication.properties ao invés do .yaml , não sei se por conta de eu usar linux limita algo.

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).